# Magento 2 Overriding a custom module

Tags: php, magento, magento2.2

So in summary I'm trying to override a third party module to include an extra dropdown menu on the admin Ui

Heres the third party file at
    Prince/Productattach/Block/Adminhtml/Productattach/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
namespace Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab;

 /**
 *Class Main
 *@package Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab
 */

 class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements 
 \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
 */
private  $systemStore;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
 */
private $customerCollection;

/**
 * Main constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerCollection
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerCollection,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->_customerCollection = $customerCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare form
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function _prepareForm()
{

    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('productattach');

    /*
     * Checking if user have permissions to save information
     */
    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Prince_Productattach::save')) {
        $isElementDisabled = false;
    } else {
        $isElementDisabled = true;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('productattach_main_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('Attachment Information')]
    );

    $customerGroup = $this->customerCollection->toOptionArray();

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('productattach_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'productattach_id']);
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __('Attachment Name'),
            'title' => __('Attachment Name'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'description',
        'textarea',
        [
            'name' => 'description',
            'label' => __('Description'),
            'title' => __('Description'),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'files',
        'file',
        [
            'name' => 'file',
            'label' => __('File'),
            'title' => __('File'),
            'required' => false,
            'note' => 'File size must be less than 2 Mb.', // TODO: show ACCTUAL file-size
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addType(
        'uploadedfile',
        \Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Renderer\FileIconAdmin::class
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'file',
        'uploadedfile',
        [
            'name'  => 'uploadedfile',
            'label' => __('Uploaded File'),
            'title' => __('Uploaded File'),

        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'url',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'url',
            'label' => __('URL'),
            'title' => __('URL'),
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
            'note' => 'Upload file or Enter url'
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'customer_group',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'customer_group[]',
            'label' => __('Customer Group'),
            'title' => __('Customer Group'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => [0,1,2,3], // todo: preselect ALL customer groups, not just 0-3
            'values' => $customerGroup,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'store',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'store[]',
            'label' => __('Store'),
            'title' => __('Store'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => [0],
            'values' => $this->systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'active',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'active',
            'label' => __('Active'),
            'title' => __('Active'),
            'value' => 1,
            'options' => ['1' => __('Yes'), '0' => __('No')],
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_productattach_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', ['form' => $form]);

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Attachment Information');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Attachment Information');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check permission for passed action
 *
 * @param string $resourceId
 * @return bool
 */
public function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
}
}
```

I have my module setup and my di.xml configured with the usual plus below to override the class.

```
<preference for="Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab" type="Vendor\Filecategory\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab"/>
```

then and exact replica of the class with namespace and my extra field added at 
Vendor/Filecategory/Block/Adminhtml/Productattach/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
namespace Vendor\Filecategory\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab;

use \Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Edit\Tab\Main as Main;


 class MainExt extends Main
 {
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
 */
private  $systemStore;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
 */
private $customerCollection;

/**
 * Main constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerCollection
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerCollection,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->customerCollection = $customerCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data, $systemStore);
}

/**
 * Prepare form
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function _prepareForm()
{

    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('productattach');

    /*
     * Checking if user have permissions to save information
     */
    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Prince_Productattach::save')) {
        $isElementDisabled = false;
    } else {
        $isElementDisabled = true;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('productattach_main_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('Attachment Information')]
    );

    $customerGroup = $this->customerCollection->toOptionArray();

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('productattach_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'productattach_id']);
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __('Attachment Name'),
            'title' => __('Attachment Name'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'Category',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'Category',
            'label' => __('Category'),
            'title' => __('Category'),
            'value' => 0,
            'options' => ['0' => __('Technical Specification'), '1' => __('Installation Instructions')],
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'description',
        'textarea',
        [
            'name' => 'description',
            'label' => __('Description'),
            'title' => __('Description'),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'files',
        'file',
        [
            'name' => 'file',
            'label' => __('File'),
            'title' => __('File'),
            'required' => false,
            'note' => 'File size must be less than 2 Mb.', // TODO: show ACCTUAL file-size
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addType(
        'uploadedfile',
        \Prince\Productattach\Block\Adminhtml\Productattach\Renderer\FileIconAdmin::class
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'file',
        'uploadedfile',
        [
            'name'  => 'uploadedfile',
            'label' => __('Uploaded File'),
            'title' => __('Uploaded File'),

        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'url',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'url',
            'label' => __('URL'),
            'title' => __('URL'),
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
            'note' => 'Upload file or Enter url'
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'customer_group',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'customer_group[]',
            'label' => __('Customer Group'),
            'title' => __('Customer Group'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => [0,1,2,3], // todo: preselect ALL customer groups, not just 0-3
            'values' => $customerGroup,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'store',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'store[]',
            'label' => __('Store'),
            'title' => __('Store'),
            'required' => true,
            'value' => [0],
            'values' => $this->systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'active',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'active',
            'label' => __('Active'),
            'title' => __('Active'),
            'value' => 1,
            'options' => ['1' => __('Yes'), '0' => __('No')],
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_productattach_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', ['form' => $form]);

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Attachment Information');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Attachment Information');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check permission for passed action
 *
 * @param string $resourceId
 * @return bool
 */
public function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
}
}
```

However I keep getting Error

```
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store. Actual type: array;
```

I have tried flush cache and reindex but no luck. Please can someone tell me what im doing wrong here? Also happy to listen to any alternative ways of completing the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to complete this by creating a plugin class instead of overriding the whole class. I have attached the post I followed for any one interested in adding a form field to n existing form attached to a third part module.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174209/magento-2-add-new-field-to-magento-user-admin-form